# How can I scroll into an image comparison slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slider

I have a lot of images and I want to compare them with an image comparison slider but I can't see the entire image only a part of it. And I want to scroll into it to be able to see the entire image.

My HTML code looks like this :

```
<div class="overflow-scroll" id="image-comparison-slider">
    <img class="overflow-scroll" width="100%" id="image1" src="../../static/img/screenshot.png" alt="before">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img width="100%" id="image2" alt="after" src="../../static/img/screenshot1.png"/>
    </div>
    <span class="label label-before">Before</span>
    <span class="label label-after">After</span>
    <div class="handle">
      <div class="handle-line"></div>
      <div class="handle-circle">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="handle-line"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I tried to use overflow-scroll from bootstrap 5 but it didn't work.

Now it look like this:
[image]

And I want to scroll down into the both images in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent div overflow-y: scroll so that, you can scroll to see the whole image. and here I am using bootstrap carousel to see all the images.

```css
.carousel {
        height: 600px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .carousel-inner {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    img {
        height: auto
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                 <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/red-flowers-1659044733.jpeg"
                    class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://cf.ltkcdn.net/small-pets/images/orig/304120-1600x1066-lovebirds-as-pets.jpg"
                    class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="http://www.evolo.us/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/0516-0.jpg"
                    class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"
            data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"
            data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```